# Opening a WAL sqlite DB read-only

Tags: sqlite

I have a WAL DB on read-only media (that is, `db.sqlite`, `db.sqlite-wal` and `db.sqlite-shm`).

I know I can't open it readonly just like that because according to the docs, [*"even ordinary reads in WAL mode require recovery-like operations"*](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#readonly).

But can I tell sqlite to open it *into* memory, and doing the recovery from read-only WAL files in memory?

So that I would end up with a recovered and fully operational in-memory DB that has the same contents as the files on disks.

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: @CL. I'm on Linux. I'd hope that if it were possible, it would be so using sqlite library functions so the OS doesn't matter. However, if there's a way that only works on some OSs, I'd still appreciate to learn about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copy the files to a RAM disk (wherever a `tmpfs` is mounted).

This could have been avoided by following the [recommendation](https://www.sqlite.org/wal.html#readonly) that

> SQLite databases should always be converted to PRAGMA journal_mode=DELETE prior to being transferred to read-only media.